# UWP App with Multiple Subscription Tiers and Upgrades

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store

Here is what I want to do, but not sure if it is possible with UWP apps using Windows Store subscription.

I would like a free app with two different subscription levels with different price points.  Example:  Use the free version, subscribe to the basic version with a core feature set, or subscribe to a pro version with advanced feature set.

I can get that setup easy enough.  My problem is this... how to handle a user that initially subscribes to the basic version then decides they want to upgrade to the pro version before the first, basic subscription expires.

Anyone have ideas?  There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do that.

Comment: maybe you can mke a 4th subscription for those who are upgrading from basic to pro version? and make that pro subscription relatively cheaper than direct pro version? this way your user will have a discount and the money they spend before on basic version wont go to waste

Comment: I had thought that as well, but the problem is that if they get the basic sub on 10/1/18 then the upgrade on 11/1/18, there is a one month gap between subscriptions renewal.  Accounting and tracking for that gap would be a pain.

Comment: I think you need a generic solution here to deal with multi tier subscriptions which is not specific to uwp, and then u can apply that solution here as well.